# Programmatically appending content without losing html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some problems with this script below:

```
<article>
  Si potrebbe comunemente pensare che i passaporti americani e britannici siano più potenti, da un punto di vista turistico, rispetto a quelli degli altri Paesi del mondo. Nel senso che permettano più accessi senza bisogno di visto. In realtà non è vero, e lhanno scoperto quelli della ditta britannica Henley & Partners sui visti Partners Index, utilizzando i dati del International Air Transport Association (IATA).
 <br>
 <br> Sono i tedeschi, in base a questi dati, ad avere i passaporti più forti, che danno loro l'accesso senza visto a 177 Paesi. L'indice classifica 199 Paesi in base alla libertà di viaggio che ognuno di questi offre ai suoi cittadini su un massimo di 218.</article>
```

Javascript

```
var know = "che;più";

function CheckKnowWords() {
  if (know != null) {
    know = know.split(";");
    var words = $("article").text().split(" ");
    $("article").empty();
    $.each(words, function(i, v) {

      if (know.indexOf(v) > -1) {
        IKnow = "true";
      } else {
        IKnow = "false";
      }

      if (IKnow == "true") {
        $("article").append(" ");
        $("article").append(v + " ");
      } else {
        $("article").append(" ");
        $("article").append($("<span style='border-radius: 4px;border: 1px solid #ffcccc; background: #ffcccc;'>").text(v));
      }
    });
  } else {
    var words = $("article").text().split(" ");
    $("article").empty();
    $.each(words, function(i, v) {
      $("article").append(" ");
      $("article").append($("<span style='border-radius: 4px;border: 1px solid #ffcccc; background: #ffcccc;'>").text(v));
    });
  }
}
```

Here a jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/fabiobraglin/ww7uLvd1/1/

This script is working well to identify the words, but I'm losing the HTML tags, `<br>` or `<b>` for example... how can I do the same thing, but without change the HTML tags inside the text?

Comment: Please explain what the code is trying to accomplish, what your current solution does and why that is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `.text` to `.html` and you should be fine:

```
var know = "che;più";

function CheckKnowWords() {
  if (know != null) {
    know = know.split(";");
    var words = $("article").html().split(" ");
    $("article").empty();
    $.each(words, function(i, v) {
      for (var j = 0; j < know.length; j++) {
        if (know[j].match(v)) {
          IKnow = "true";
        } else {
          IKnow = "false";
        }
      }
      if (IKnow == "true") {
        $("article").append(" ");
        $("article").append(v + " ");
      } else {
        $("article").append(" ");
        $("article").append($("<span style='border-radius: 4px;border: 1px solid #ffcccc; background: #ffcccc;'>").html(v));
      }
    });
  } else {
    var words = $("article").html().split(" ");
    $("article").empty();
    $.each(words, function(i, v) {
      $("article").append(" ");
      $("article").append($("<span style='border-radius: 4px;border: 1px solid #ffcccc; background: #ffcccc;'>").html(v));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @jehna1, your solution works... Tks! I will need to wait some minutes to mark as solved...